# parseInt error in my code

Tags: parseint

I get error messages in my code. Code and errors is below.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String sayi[] = {"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",  
             "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",  
             "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",  
             "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",  
             "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",  
             "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",  
             "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",  
             "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",  
             "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",  
             "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",  
             "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",  
             "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",  
             "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",  
             "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",  
             "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",  
             "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",  
             "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",  
             "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",  
             "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",  
             "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",  
             "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",  
             "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",  
             "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",  
             "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",  
             "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",  
             "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",  
             "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",  
             "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",  
             "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",  
             "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",  
             "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",  
             "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",  
             "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",  
             "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",  
             "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",  
             "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",  
             "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",  
             "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",  
             "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",  
             "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",  
             "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",  
             "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",  
             "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",  
             "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",  
             "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",  
             "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",  
             "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",  
             "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",  
             "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",  
             "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",  
             "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",  
             "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",  
             "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",  
             "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",  
             "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",  
             "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",  
             "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",  
             "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",  
             "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",  
             "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",  
             "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",  
             "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",  
             "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",  
             "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",  
             "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",  
             "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",  
             "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",  
             "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",  
             "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",  
             "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",  
             "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",  
             "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",  
             "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",  
             "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",  
             "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",  
             "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",  
             "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",  
             "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",  
             "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",  
             "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",  
             "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",  
             "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",  
             "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",  
             "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",  
             "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",  
             "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",  
             "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",  
             "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",  
             "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",  
             "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",  
             "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",  
             "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",  
             "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",  
             "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",  
             "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",  
             "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",  
             "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",  
             "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",  
             "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",  
             "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690"};

        int no[] = new int[100];
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            no[i] = Integer.parseInt(sayi[i].substring(0, 10));
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            sum += no[k];
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3710728753"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

This error is about this line:

```
no[i] = Integer.parseInt(sayi[i].substring(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range of an int is about -2 to 2 milliards. 10-digit numbers don't fit in that range.
Try to parse a long or a float there.